# How to align an ion-avatar inside an ion-col

Tags: ionic-framework, ion-grid

I am developing a simple app with Ionic v4 framework, and I have an ion-grid like this:

```
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col *ngFor="let item of items">
            <ion-avatar>
                <img src="{{item.getItemImgUrl()}}" />
            </ion-avatar>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
        ..........
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

May anyone tell me how I can align the ion-avatar exactly in the center of the ion-col?

I've tried `text-align: center;` in my css sheet, but it doesn't work.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try <ion-col align-self-center>

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I solved it by using

```
<ion-col style="display: flex; justify-content: center">
```